# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: authentication_user.name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, migration, django-migrations

I was trying to add a new field to my User authentication model. But whenever I'm trying to run **python manage.py makemigrations**, the console is showing,

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: authentication_user.name

Here is a part of my Model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4, 
                          editable=False,blank=False, null=False)
    cus_id = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True, blank=True, 
                              default=increment_cus_number)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank = True, null = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, default = '', blank = True, null = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True, null= True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    business_partner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    auth_provider = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False,
        null=False, default=AUTH_PROVIDERS.get('email'))

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

any suggestions/tips regarding this issue would be a great help.

Comment: for quick you might want to consider the droping the DB, if not please your migrations folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running:

```
py manage.py migrate
```

It seems the columns in the database have not been created yet. If that doesn't work:

- Delete migration files from your project, folder structure for migrations should look like this after clearing:

```
/migrations
    /__init__.py
```

- Makemigrations to re-generate the migrations.
- Migrate to create all nescessary DB tables, columns, etc.

Comment: I tried that already but unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use are calling User.name in some where. When we start server django will check that column in database that may not migrated at our database.

One solution is try to find out where you called that User.name and use correct login.

Or try dropping the database and all migrations files; migrate again.

AFTER DROPPING DATABASE

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -path "*/venv/*" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc" -not -path "*/venv/*" -delete
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider deleting the migrations in migrations directory and then proceed to migrate with the command
`python manage.py migrate`
Maybe you already executed the line
`python manage.py makemigrations` before.
This worked for similar issue I had where I had already executed the line.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem. It was caused by an import of the particular model in another model.py file (from user.models import User). Just remove the import and then run migrations.